# Java JAR - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jar

Im working on **Ubuntu**. I made simple GUI app which uses 3 classes. Main is Test.class which contains main method. I have packed them all into JAR from console level. Now I have "kalkulator.jar" which contains: Test.class, MyFrame.class, MyPanel.class and META-INF folder. In META_INf there is MANIFEST.MF. What is in MANIFEST.MF is: "Main-Class: Test" and newline character. Now I try to open my JAR from console using:
java -jar kalkulator.jar
I get: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test (wrong name: myproject/Test")
myproject is package of all my classes.
So how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the 'package' statement in Test.java?

Comment: Then your manifest has to say MainClass: myproject.Test

Comment: Now I get Error: Could not find or load main class myproject.Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following things:

1. make sure that the directory hierarchy in your jar matches the package hierarchy, absolutely. The classes have to be in a directory named 'myproject' in the jar. If they are just at top level, it won't work.
2. Make the Main-Class name the fully qualified name of the class with the main method. (i.e. myproject.Test).
3. Learn to use a build tool, e.g. ant, to do all this.